# I want to find each item in the list that contains a specific value

Tags: python

Assuming I have this list:

```
Schedule = [
        {"math": True,
         "science": False,
         "history": True,
         "spanish": False},

        {"math": False,
         "science": True,
         "history": False,
         "spanish": True,},

        {"math": True,
         "science": True,
         "history": False,
         "spanish": False},
]
```

I want to find all items in the list where `"math": True` and return their index number.
For example, it should be 0 and 2 from the code above.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: `[i for i,j in enumerate(Schedule) if j['math']]`?

Answer (score 0):

like *BTables* pointed, you can use enumerate to do this:

```
print([(i for i,j in enumerate(Schedule) if j["maths"])])
```

out:

```
[0,2]
```

or, if you want the full list:

```
for x in Schedule[0].keys():
    print([i for i,j in enumerate(Schedule) if j[x]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
schedule = [
        {"math": True,
         "science": False,
         "history": True,
         "spanish": False},

        {"math": False,
         "science": True,
         "history": False,
         "spanish": True,},

        {"math": True,
         "science": True,
         "history": False,
         "spanish": False},
]

def validate(course, val):
    return [i for i,j in enumerate(schedule) if j[course]==val]
        
print(validate('math', True))
print(validate('history', False))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
```